# How to change the color of the primary Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have theme like this:

```
export const Original = createMuiTheme({
palette: {
    type: 'light',
    primary: {
        light: '#b2dfdb',
        main: '#26a69a',
        dark: '#004d40',
    }
}
});
```

And I use it for this:

```
<ListItem color = 'primary' button >
    <img src={APP} alt='' />
</ListItem>
```

how can I use the `primary-light` or `primary-dark` for `ListItem`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read Material UI documentation. You would know that `List` & `ListItem` don't have `props` `color`. Thus in order for you to add one or apply any other colors as you wish, you can do something like this:-

- `App.js` (require: `ThemeProvider` & `createMuiTheme` from `@material-ui/core/styles`)

```
import React from "react";
import { ThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import "./style.css";
import Demo from "./Demo";

export default function App() {
  const lightTheme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      type: "light",
      primary: {
        light: "#b2dfdb",
        main: "#26a69a",
        dark: "#004d40"
      }
    }
  });

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={lightTheme}>
      <Demo />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

- `Demo.js` (require: `makeStyles` or 'useTheme' from `@material-ui/stlyes`):-

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles, useTheme } from "@material-ui/styles";
import { List, ListItem } from "@material-ui/core";
import "./style.css";

const Demo = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const theme = useTheme();

  return (
    <>
      <List>
        <ListItem className={classes.listItem}>
          Using useStyles (classes)
        </ListItem>
        <ListItem style={{ color: theme.palette.primary.dark }}>
          Using inline direct theme
        </ListItem>
      </List>
      <List className={classes.list}>
        <ListItem>Having List control over all ListItem styles</ListItem>
      </List>
    </>
  );
};

export default Demo;

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  listItem: {
    color: theme.palette.primary.light
  },
  list: {
    color: theme.palette.primary.main
  }
}));
```

Here are the working [sandbox code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-9rtvkx?file=src%2FDemo.js) you can refer to.

Comment: so how do I use this for class component ( the Demo component )?

Comment: you just need to declare the `const classes = useStyles();` & `const theme = useTheme();` inside your `class` component `render`. Other than that, the usage still work the same.